# How to grab byte array after serialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, activemq-classic, serialization, flatbuffers

I'm using Google's Flatbuffer. I've created a simple schema for C++ that just takes a name and ID as the fields. After creating the auto generated code and running the fields through the CreateDetails() function, how would I get the bytearray to pass into ActiveMQ? I've searched around but couldn't find much about the byte array.

My schema:

```
table details {
    name:string;
    id: int;
};

root_type details;
```

My .cpp application:

```
auto name = builder.CreateString("some text here");
auto id = 25;

auto detail = CreateDetails(builder, name, id);

builder.Finish(detail);
```

Now, from my understanding, the sample message should be serialized, but I'm not sure how to grab the serialized data as a byte array. I was able to access the root and just go down the tree and look at the data, but I want to grab the entire message as a bytearray.

Please and thank you!

Comment: [`builder.GetBufferPointer()`](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/classflatbuffers_1_1_flat_buffer_builder.html#ab81ab8aa273c270b0942fd81489cad83)

Comment: @MilesBudnek That's it? That's what I've been doing, I just didn't realize that was the entire byte array.....

Comment: To be precise, starting from `GetBufferPointer()` for `GetSize()` bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
builder.GetBufferPointer()
builder.GetSize()
```